# How do I make this batch file become a command?

Tags: batch-file, colors, command

I have a batch file called *colortxt.bat*, and I need it to be a command with these properties:

You use the color format (hex) used in the *color* command (`0f` is a background and foreground) with the 2 b/f values. Then to display the colored text I put **" "** (inside the quotes any message can be specified), and it does it for me.

Here is the code (originally code by *jeb*.):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
```

Here was the code you would use on a program. This is edited and uses a syntax like this:

```
call: ColorText (color code hex) "Hello World!"

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

Comment: I didn't notice that, yes it is `call :label`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is. Just call the batch file like `call colortxt.bat 0f "Hello world!"`

Comment: I want this to be the syntax: ´colortxt 0f "Hello Cats!"´

Comment: So stick it in one of the directories listed in your path variable.

Comment: There's no "path" variable, i don't know why the new codes on the stackoverflow thread make a file called "X", it's useless anyway.

Comment: I absolutely guarantee you that your Windows operating system has a system variable called `%PATH%`. Open a command prompt, type `echo %PATH%`, pick one of the folders that is listed, and put your script in there.

Comment: Alright, it did some input but it seems it actually was on a PowerShell folder, not CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the batch file in System32, if that fails, put it in whatever %PATH% is.

Comment: I'm making consumer software, so this isn't an option.

Comment: @Star OS I don't understand why that matters.

Comment: I don't want to well, DUH, place something in System32.

Comment: @StarOS I don't see why not..?

Answer (score -1):

While @SomethingDark mentions using `ECHO %path%` all you need to do is type `PATH` in the command prompt.

Then you simply save the batch file into one of those directories/folders.  Now close command prompt and open it again.  Enter the name of the batch file and it will execute.

Additionally, in the Control Panel, open System (might have to change the view from Categories to Icons) and click Advanced System Settings.  On the System Properties dialog box which opens, click Environment Variables.  Under System Variables scroll to PATH and double click it to edit.  The Variable Value should be fully selected, simply use CTRL + C to copy the path.  Paste this into Notepad to edit.  You can add a new folder to your path by using a semicolon `;` to separate the folders listed.

Comment: I'm making a consumer software, and i don't want to put something in the PATH folder.

Comment: Beacuse i don't WANT THAT

Comment: No, you don't have to put anything in the existing `PATH` folder.  You just add to the existing `PATH` listing to include the folder path to  your software.  Which is what I explained in the last paragraph.